# Save multiple form

Tags: php, symfony

Having this Entity for example:

```
<?php

namespace Gitek\HotelBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Gitek\HotelBundle\Entity\Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gitek\HotelBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;
```

How to build a Form to save like 10 products on a row? I want a form with a "+" button and dinamically add line and submit all products in a row.

any help or clue?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Javascript(jQuery) to add the form elements to your page dynamically when you click the "Add" button. Something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

                var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

                if (newNum == 5)
                    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

                $('#input' + num).remove();
                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="myForm">
    <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" />
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[Reference](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/)
Then when the form is posted, you can walk through the `$_POST` array.

Comment: That was helfull but in symfony, to create an array first you have to change the name of the fields. It works with jQuery and simply adding [] to the end of the name itself.

Answer (score 0):

That is very least amount of code, to see your working process.

But basically such tasks are solved, by storing all the information on the **session** as a multidimensional array and finally inserting them **one by one** on the last point.